# GoogleSpeechAPI (C#) Detecting language spoken automatically

Tags: c#, google-speech-api

I've installed GoogleSpeechAPI 1.1.0-beta03 (C#) and tried to implement new functionality: [Detecting language spoken automatically](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-languages)

But **RecognitionConfig** class does not have **alternativeLanguageCodes** property? Is this not available yet for C# client library?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was the problem. For c# library this version of library must be used.

Nuget:

```
Install-Package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1 -Version 1.0.0-beta03
```